# What is the largest number representable by BigInt?

Tags: javascript

What is the largest number representable by `BigInt` in Javascript?

I am unable to represent some particularly large numbers in JS, and am getting an error instead.

Answer (score 1):

The largest number representable by BigInt is implementation defined.

For V8, this limit is at about 1 million bits of precision, 2<sup>1000000</sup> (A very big int!). This results in about 301,030 decimal digits of precision.